# bind JSON list in array to ASP.NET model class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am building JSON output from my array that I am intended to pass back to server where I have model class to bind JSON data variable to class variables. In this class I am also taking multiple records of say for argument 'Component' and to bind this part I have IList in my model class.

Now I have managed to pass data back to controller except the Components that is in IList... I am struggling to find answer.. your help will be really appreciated..

### Model class

```
 public class QualificationElementComponents_ViewModel
{

    public int ElementIndex { get; set; }
    public string ElementMarkingSchemeTitle { get; set; }
    public int ElementAvailableMark { get; set; }
    public int ElementPassMark { get; set; }
    public int ElementMeritMark { get; set; }
    public int ElementDistinctionMark { get; set; }

    public IList<ECom1> ElementComponent { get; set; }

}
```

### IList 'Component' Model class

```
 public class ECom1
{
    public int componentIndex { get; set; }
    public int componentMark { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller Method

```
  public ActionResult CreateNewQualification(QualificationViewModel newQualificationData, IList<QualificationElementComponents_ViewModel> ElementComponentList)
   {
```

### in view

```
//build component list... possible will have multiple records in array
selectedComponentList.push({ componentIndex: recordId, componentMark: ComponentSchemeMark });

// build element list
selectElementList.push({ ElementIndex: E_RecordId, ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: E_MarkingSchemeTitle, ElementAvailableMark: E_AvailableMark, ElementPassMark: E_PassMark, ElementMeritMark: E_MeritMark, ElementDistinctionMark: E_DistinctionMark });

 //bind arrays 

 selectElementList.push({ ElementComponent: selectedComponentList });

        QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList.push.apply(QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList, selectElementList);
```

### JSON Output

```
{"QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList":[{"ElementIndex":1,"ElementMarkingSchemeTitle":"fg","ElementAvailableMark":"56","ElementPassMark":"6","ElementMeritMark":"5","ElementDistinctionMark":"6"},{"ElementComponent":[{"componentIndex":1,"componentMark":"23"},{"componentIndex":2,"componentMark":"44"}]}]}
```

### require JSON Output

in comparison to above JSON I require following JSON format

```
{"QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList":[{"ElementIndex":1,"ElementMarkingSchemeTitle":"d2","ElementAvailableMark":"223","ElementPassMark":"32","ElementMeritMark":"12","ElementDistinctionMark":"2","ElementComponent":[{"componentIndex":2,"componentMark":551}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the ElementComponent property to a new object and then into the array, you need to include it with the other properties like so:

```
    //build component list... possible will have multiple records in array
    selectedComponentList.push({ componentIndex: recordId, componentMark: ComponentSchemeMark });

    // build element list
    selectElementList.push({ ElementIndex: E_RecordId, ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: E_MarkingSchemeTitle, ElementAvailableMark: E_AvailableMark, ElementPassMark: E_PassMark, ElementMeritMark: E_MeritMark, ElementDistinctionMark: E_DistinctionMark, ElementComponent: selectedComponentList });
    //Add ElementComponent with all the other properties
```

Comment: but my issue is i got to take element before component at different places i don't have the choice

Comment: @toxic, You can add the ElementComponent property initially as an empty array like: `ElementComponent: []` then later on update the object in the selectedElementList. Or is this not feasible?